# Handling Custom URI in Delphi XE5 Android App

Tags: android, delphi

I have managed to register a custom protocol handler in my XE5 Android app by modifying the Androidmanifest.template.xml file.  My application pops up properly whenever a myapp://myurl URL is clicked on.

The problem is, I need to get the URL that was clicked on when the app is launched in order to bring up the correct part of the app.  Can anyone help me figure out how to get this?

Comment: I don't have anything set up to test this, but have you checked to see if it's passed in a command line parameter (using `ParamCount` and `ParamStr()`?

Comment: That was the first thing I tried.  It is not passed in Paramstr.  Thank you for the response though.

Answer (score 2):

Based on [this example](http://snipplr.com/view/49930/), try something like this:

```
uses
  ...,
  Androidapi.JNI.GraphicsContentViewText,
  Androidapi.JNI.Net,
  FMX.Helpers.Android;

procedure TMainForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  intent: JIntent;
  uri: Jnet_Uri;
  uriStr: String;
begin
  intent := SharedActivity.getIntent;
  if intent <> nil then
  begin
    if TJIntent.JavaClass.ACTION_VIEW.equals(intent.getAction) then
    begin
      uri := intent.getData;
      uriStr := JStringToString(uri.toString);
      // use uriStr as needed...
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I did try your code, I think it's closer than what I had, but it intent.getAction still raises the exception ALOOPER_POLL_ERROR and the program crashes.

Comment: @Mike: your edit was wrong, so I removed it. `ACTION_VIEW` and `getAction()` both return `JString` interface pointers, not Delphi `String` values. You cannot compare `JString` pointers directly, that is why the original code was using the `JString.equals()` method. I restored that code. If you want to compare the string values using Delphi sematics, you would have to use `JStringToString()` to convert them first.

Comment: @RobbieR: what do you mean "still raises the exception"? You did not mention anything about an exception in your question.

Comment: I apologize, I just worded it incorrectly.  The code compiles but raises an exception.  I shouldn't have used the word "still".  I just meant that it wasn't working.

Comment: Sorry, I can't help with that exception, that error is way out of my realm of expertise. You are sure it is `intent.getAction()` that is raising the error?