# How to find the file passed to a Delphi app on Android?

Tags: android, file, delphi

We must write an Android app who knows how to open .xyz files.

However when we assign the .xyz files to our application, and after that we tap on an .xyz file in the Android's File Explorer, the application is properly started but the program doesn't see the file name as a parameter.

The code

```
  ShowMessage(ParamStr(0)); //for debug...
  ShowMessage(ParamStr(1));
```

Instead of showing in message boxes the application's full path and after this the full path of the tapped (clicked) file name it shows two empty strings.

**How can we get the full path of the tapped (clicked) file?**

*UPDATE:*

(A part of) The manifest looks like this:

```
    <activity android:name="com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity"
            android:label="MMBook"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
        <!-- Tell NativeActivity the name of our .so -->
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name"
            android:value="MMBook" />
        <intent-filter>  
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter> 
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="file"  android:host="*" android:pathPattern=".*\\.mma" android:mimeType="*/*"  />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `SharedActivity.getIntent()` to check if your app was started by an `Intent` or not.  If a non-nil `Intent` is returned, you can retrieve its data (ie, the filename) and act accordingly.  See my answer to the following question for an example:

[Handling Custom URI in Delphi XE5 Android App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20457760/handling-custom-uri-in-delphi-xe5-android-app)
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20465775/65863

Answer (score 1):

On Android, launching an activity and passing a file from a different app is implemented with Intents and Intent filters. (See [Allowing Other Apps to Start Your Activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/filters.html))

So usually your app must implement an Intent handler. In order to decide what action to take in your activity, you can read the Intent that was used to start it.

The URI of the selected file then can be retrieved with `Intent.getData()`

Java Example:

```
// Get the intent that started this activity
Intent intent = getIntent();
Uri data = intent.getData();

// Figure out what to do based on the intent type
if (intent.getType().indexOf("image/") != -1) {
    // Handle intents with image data ...
} else if (intent.getType().equals("text/plain")) {
    // Handle intents with text ...
}
```

See also: http://codeverge.com/embarcadero.delphi.firemonkey/android-intent-filter-associate/1057456

Comment: Don't forget to check if `getIntent()` returns a `nil` pointer, indicating that the app was started normally. Also, this answer is not written with Delphi in mind (the snippet is not in Delphi syntax, nor does it show how to call `getIntent()` in Delphi).